# Where to configure lift env to production that hides the stack traces?

Tags: scala, configuration, lift, production

I deployed my lift application to production. However, I found that the stack traces are not hidden. Where is the place to set the environment configuration to production in lift, so that the stack traces will no longer show?

Comment: Take a look at [SimplyLift 3.1.2 Properties and Run modes](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.1.html#toc-Subsection-3.1.2) It answers your question regarding Lift's run mods and how/where to configure it.

Comment: But it does not hide the stack trace even if I configure it to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tomcat you can set this setting in:

```
/etc/tomcat6/catalina.properties
```

If you want to test this behaveour with SBT, use:

```
./sbt -Drun.mode=production
```

Comment: Under resin, it's in resin.conf